# How to modify multiple objects in the same OOP class?

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7

I have created a program from my textbook that deals with animals or `Critters()`.
At the moment it deals with only a single critter.

The problem is now the textbook has asked me to create multiple critters, and instead of the functions working on a single critter, the functions should instead work on all of the critters.

I have zero idea how to do this.

**So, how can I pass arguments to the multiple critters?**

Here's my attempt (*code snippet*):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pcrit.py", line 76, in main
    animal.eat(units)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'eat'
```

**^error^**

```
import random

class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet."""
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.boredom = random.randrange(0,30)
        self.hunger = random.randrange(0,30)
        print "A new critter is born:", self.name, "\n"

    def eat(self, food):
        food = int(food)
        self.hunger -= food
        if self.hunger < 0:
            self.hunger = 0

# main

critters = ["donkey","monkey","dog","horse"]
# make each animal into the Critter() class
for animal in critters:
    animal = Critter(animal)

units = (raw_input("How many play units? "))
for animal in critters:
    animal.eat(units)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through

```
critters = ["donkey","monkey","dog","horse"]
```

Those are strings, they don't have methods like `eat`.

Instead, you need to make a list of `Critter`s

```
critters = [Critter(name) for name in ["donkey", "monkey", "dog", "horse"]]
```

What you are doing:

```
for animal in critters:
    animal = Critter(animal)
```

Doesn't assign the new objects back to the list `critters`.

Comment: I don't understand why iterating through the list doesn't work. It works manually if I type donkey.eat(units)

Comment: @user2071506 yes, but you aren't putting the `Critter` instance back into the list, so you always iterate over the strings.

Comment: @JonClements where would I be without you!

Comment: @jonrsharpe someone said that earlier in Python chat :)... my response remains the same - "you'd be left in peace" :p

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, I think I understand... So you mean the For loop is literally doing this: `"donkey".eat(units)`?
I don't fully understand the code in your answer, so I'm trying to work it out in my head more for an easier solution.

Comment: @user2071506 yes, exactly

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems your code is doing the same thing; seems to be strings. Why is it different?

Comment: Because you create `Critter` objects, assign them to the name `animal`, but don't put them back into the list `critters`